# How can I use the "fvisibiltiy=hidden" option on the Crashlytics-ndk?

Tags: hidden, crashlytics-android

How can I use the "fvisibiltiy=hidden" option on the Crashlytics-ndk?
It's a different problem than a symbol.
If this option is used, no module offset can be found.

```
Crashlytics report:
  Crashed: com.me.fabrictest|
  0  libnative-lib.so               0xb3a82364 (Missing)
  1  base.odex                      0xb399d1e7 oatexec
```

Comment: are you trying to load libnative-lib.so ?

Comment: libnative-lib.so is already loaded.
The crash that occurred on that module.

void CrashSubProc2()
{
    int *p = NULL;
    *p = 1234; // Crash test
}